# fit a curve with Math.Net that pass through origin

Tags: curve-fitting, mathnet-numerics

I have a set of (Xi,Yi) point that should be fitted by 3rd degree polynomial function that pass through zero.

I consider to use MathNet.Numerics for this task, but I don't see in the [documentation](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics/Fit.htm) 
an option to force the fitted function to pass through origin. If this option is not supported, please suggest a solution that uses functions included in latest release of MathNet.Numerics.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume you know that this is how you would fit some data in Math.Net

```
Func<Double, Double> MyFunc = Fit.PolynomialFunc(xDataArr, yDataArr, 3);
```

As for forcing it through the origin I have never seen an option for that. I think the only real solution is to put the point `(0, 0)` into your data set and hope for the best?.

Something you can try that doesn't really make mathematical sense at all is to put the point `(0, 0)` in your data set multiple times.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Fit data with Math.Net is straightforward. Adding (0,0) to the data is not equivalent to constrain the plot to pass through (0,0). I just wonder if I can workaround this limitation within the current version.

Comment: I have been through `Fit` a few times I have never seen something to allow such a constraint. And yes I understand that adding `(0, 0)` to the data does not strictly constrain it. // Another option you might have is to get the function coefficients instead of the `Func` and then modify the coefficients to your needs?

Comment: Pass through origin is equivalent to "Set Intercept=0" in Excel. Here are two ways to solve this problem with Matlab: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94272-how-do-i-constrain-a-fitted-curve-through-specific-points-like-the-origin-in-matlab            http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35401-polyfitzero